# Prevent concurrent method execution and blocks

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

I'm writing a class to centralize remote calls to my backend.
The calls have to be authenticated with oauth, so in each methods, I first check if my token is valide, if not, I request a refreshed one.

Each method looks like this:

```
-(void)getRemoteDataAndRun:(nullable void(^)(NSDictionary * __nullable json))success
           orFail:(nullable void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * __nullable operation, NSError * __nullable error))failure {
    [self checkOAuthTokenAndRun:^{
        // my remote call
        ...
        success(json);
    } orFail:failure];
}
```

the method **checkOAuthTokenAndRun** check the token validity and request a new one if needed.
My problem is that I have to ensure that checkOAuthTokenAndRun is not called concurrently to prevent reads of credentials while it's refreshed (written).

I tried with NSLock but with blocks (multithreading), I get the following error:

```
*** -[NSLock lock]: deadlock (<NSLock: 0x7ffd9313d9b0> '(null)')
```

Here is the complete checkOAuthTokenAndRun method:

```
- (void)checkOAuthTokenAndRun:(void (^)())action orFail:(nullable void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * __nullable operation, NSError * __nullable error))failure
{
    NSLog(@"lock oauth check/refresh");
    [oauthLock lock];

    if (credential == nil || [credential isExpired])
    {
        NSLog(@"Credentials are null or expired");

        if (credential == nil || credential.refreshToken == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Credentials are null or anonymous+expired");
            [self getAnonymousCredentialsAndRun:^{

                NSLog(@"unlock oauth");
                [oauthLock unlock];
                action();

            } orFail:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                NSLog(@"unlock oauth");
                [oauthLock unlock];
                failure(operation, error);

            }];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Credentials are expired");

            AFOAuth2Manager *OAuth2Manager = [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURL] clientID:clientId secret:clientSecret];

            [OAuth2Manager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth/v2/token" refreshToken:credential.refreshToken success:^(AFOAuthCredential *_credential) {
                credential = _credential;

                NSLog(@"Received refreshed token");

                [AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:credential
                                withIdentifier:OAuthProviderIdentifier];

                NSLog(@"unlock oauth");
                [oauthLock unlock];

                action();

            } failure:^(NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"Failed refreshing oauth token (%@)", [error localizedDescription]);

                // remove refresh token
                NSLog(@"Unable to get oauth token, delete credentials (%@)", [error localizedDescription]);
                [AFOAuthCredential deleteCredentialWithIdentifier:OAuthProviderIdentifier];

                credential = nil; //[AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:OAuthProviderIdentifier];

                NSLog(@"unlock oauth");
                [oauthLock unlock];

                failure(nil, error);
            }];
        }
    }
    else { // run the action
        NSLog(@"Credentials are valid (%@)", (credential.refreshToken.length ? @"refresh token defined" : @"refresh token not defined"));

        NSLog(@"unlock oauth");
        [oauthLock unlock];
        action();
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm using nested blocks, I don't know if this is the reason why I get the deadlocks.

Once again, I only want to prevent concurrent execution of **checkOAuthTokenAndRun** method

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check out promises.  The basic idea would be that validating the token would be a promise.  Every other request would chain off that promise, which doesn't execute multiple times, once it's been fulfilled.  If your token can be invalidated mid-session, you'll need to come up with a way to invalidate the promise.  I am not sure current libraries have any facility for this.  (See Bolts framework from FB, as one implementation.)

Comment: @Avi thanks, just tried PromiseKit, sounds good but does not allows to "lock" the token method concurrent access...

Answer (score 0):

Network call are concurrent and they have to be concurrent. The problem with your code is you called a concurrent method inside another method which is itself concurrent. Solution to your problem:

Call method checkOAuthTokenAndRun first and if success(response from block) then call method getRemoteDataAndRun.

```
[self checkOAuthTokenAndRun:^{

    if(success){
       [self getRemoteDataAndRun:^{

          }]
   }
  } orFail:failure];
```

//Above code snippet is just a example to solve your problem. You need redesign the blocks parameter

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I'm doing, but the code is itself embeded in an "action" method (lets say "getUserComments") with success and failure blocks, I want to prevent all action methods to call checkOAuthTokenAndRun concurrently